# How to change axis scale in lattice::xyplot

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I am relatively new to R and trying to make a figure using lattice xy plot.

Here is the current figure and data frame:

```
Plot9Pn <- c(46, 33, 28)
Plot11Pn <- c(20, 18, 10)
Plot14Pn <- c(34, 28, 26)
Plot15Pn <- c(57, 33, 12)
Plot9Pr <- c(30, 46, 95)
Plot11Pr <- c(8, 11, 14)
Plot14Pr <- c(10, 46, 46)
Plot15Pr <- c(15, 37, 110)

Pn.vs.Pr.dat <- data.frame (x=rep (2009:2011, 8), y=c(Plot9Pr, Plot9Pn, Plot11Pr, Plot11Pn, Plot14Pr, Plot14Pn, Plot15Pr, Plot15Pn),
               var=factor(rep(c("Pram","Pnem"), each=3)),
               graph=factor (rep (c(" A. Plot 9", "B. Plot 11", "C. Plot 14", "D. Plot 15"), each=6)))

require(lattice)  # no need to install but loading is required.

xyplot (y ~ x | graph, groups=var, data=Pn.vs.Pr.dat, type="o", pch=my.pch, lty=1,
    main="Changes in P. nemorosa vs. P. ramorum occurence", layout=c(1, 4), as.table=T,      xlab="Year", ylab="No. Positive",
    strip.left=T, strip=F,
    key=list (columns=2, text=list (my.text), points=list (pch=my.pch, col=my.col),
              lines=list (lty=1, col=my.col)))
```

I would like the X axis to be displayed with only three ticks as a year and change the scale of the Y axis to fit each plot.

Comment: Either define all the ditzely stuff like my.pch or strip it out of the code!

Comment: And i'm not sure why you're doing all that work for the legend. Instead of `key=`, you probably just want `auto.key=list(columns=2)`

Answer (score 5):

Just add this to the the xyplot arguments:

```
   ... , scales=list(x=list(at=c(2009,2010,2011), labels=c(2009,2010,2011))),
```

The general principles are that arguments are passed as lists, that either or both of the first arguments can be 'x'  or 'y', and that you find the available arguments in `?xyplot`.

Comment: how does this this command works for negative numbers ? I can only get to work the `...at=c(....,.....)` for positive values

Comment: There's no problem if the values correspond to the domain of the problem. However, when the domain of the  graph is outside the values for at, then nothing appears and there is no error or warning.  If this doesn't explain your difficulties then you need to post a new question with a [MCVE]